# How to update playlist of react-jinke-music-player inside in app.js

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using [react-jinke-music-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jinke-music-player) to play mp3 file. It is working fine if my mp3 list and player are in same page.
If I change another page music player stopped. It is expected.

So I add the player in app level at `app.js` using `React.createContext()` as follow.

I think global variable is updated but play's playlist is not updated.

May I know how to update the playlist of the player not in same page.

**app_context.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

const AppContext = React.createContext();

export default AppContext;
```

**app.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import Header from './components/header';
import SideMenu from './components/side_menu';
import AppRoutes from './routes';
import { AuthProvider } from './auth/auth_provider';
import withUser from './hocs/with_user';
import ReactJkMusicPlayer from 'react-jinke-music-player';
import 'react-jinke-music-player/assets/index.css';
import options from '../src/constants/autio_player';
import AppContext from './components/app_context';

function App(props) {
  const [playerOptions, setPlayerOptions] = useState(options);
  const [sideBarFull] = useState(true);

  const userSettings = {
    playerOptions,
    setPlayerOptions,
  };

  const PageHeader = () => {
    return (
      <div
        className="h-[72px] w-full flex items-center align-middle justify-center 
     bg-neutral shadow"
      >
        <div className="w-full text-center">
          <Header />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <AuthProvider user={props.user}>
      <AppContext.Provider value={userSettings}>
        <div className="relative w-full min-h-screen min-w-[480px] h-full">
          <div className="flex flex-row min-h-screen">
            <div className="w-auto z-0 ">
              <div className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen mx-auto text-lg h-full shadow-lg bg-white overflow-y-auto">
                <SideMenu showFullMenu={sideBarFull} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full max-h-screen flex flex-col z-10">
              <PageHeader />
              <div className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen mx-auto text-lg h-full shadow-lg bg-white overflow-y-auto">
                <Toaster />
                <AppRoutes />
                <ReactJkMusicPlayer {...playerOptions} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default withUser(App);
```

**playlist.js**

```js
const myContext = useContext(AppContext);
options.audioLists = playlist;
myContext.setPlayerOptions(options);
```

Comment: So you'd like to control the music player instance from another component, right? Is the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jinke-music-player-demo-with-react-context-u0tdl) similar to what you're looking for? It changes the playlist from the `SideMenu` component. Other parts of your app are removed to have a minimal working example. If this helps, I can add an answer and explain how it is working.

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what I want and It it working as expected. Thanks you so much @AWolf. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: did you checked whether your context state is receiving the playlist ?

Comment: Yes, I am receiving the playlist because, if I change something in app.js player show the playlist. But anyway, @AWolf sandbox code is working for me. I have to declare the variable when createContext instead of creating usersetting constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `App` component you're creating the state that is holding the options of your player with `const [playerOptions, setOptions] = useState(options)`

`options` are your `initialOptions` (you could also name them like this).

Next, you pass `options` and `setOptions` to your `AppContext.Provider` as the value. Then options and the setter can be used by other components.

You can place the below snippet in a separate module and export `AppContext` and the Provider. (In the below Code and the Codesandbox, everything is in one file.)

Also creating a `useAppContext` or `usePlayerContext` hook could be interesting, if you're having many places where you're using it.

```js
const AppContext = createContext({
  options,
  setOptions: () => {}
});

<AppContext.Provider value={{options: playerOptions, setOptions}}>
  <SideMenu/>
</AppContext.Provider>
```

The "specialty" here is that you're using the `setOptions` reference from your `App` component everywhere where you're using it.
So it is changing the state of your app.

Now, in `SideMenu` component you can get the context with `const {options, setOptions} = useContext(AppContext)` and change the options with the `setOptions` method.
Just be careful to keep the other options and always merge them like: `setOptions({...options, audioLists: newAudiolist})` (otherwise you could accidentally  lose some options without noticing)

Optionally, you could add a check if the context is defined with

```js
const context = useContext(AppContext)
if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("AppContext was used outside of its Provider");
}
```

**Demo code:**

Sorry, the snippet below is not working here but you can check it on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jinke-music-player-demo-with-react-context-u0tdl).

```js
const { useState, createContext, useContext } = React;
//import ReactJkMusicPlayer from "react-jinke-music-player";
//import "./styles.css";
//import "react-jinke-music-player/assets/index.css";

const audioList1 = [
  {
    name: "Despacito",
    singer: "Luis Fonsi",
    cover:
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/alick/image/upload/v1502689731/Despacito_uvolhp.jpg",
    musicSrc:
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/alick/video/upload/v1502689683/Luis_Fonsi_-_Despacito_ft._Daddy_Yankee_uyvqw9.mp3"
    // support async fetch music src. eg.
    // musicSrc: async () => {
    //   return await fetch('/api')
    // },
  },
  {
    name: "Dorost Nemisham",
    singer: "Sirvan Khosravi",
    cover:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/ehsanahmadi/image/upload/v1573758778/Sirvan-Khosravi-Dorost-Nemisham_glicks.jpg",
    musicSrc:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/ehsanahmadi/video/upload/v1573550770/Sirvan-Khosravi-Dorost-Nemisham-128_kb8urq.mp3"
  }
];

const audioList2 = [
  {
    name: "Bedtime Stories",
    singer: "Jay Chou",
    cover:
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/alick/image/upload/v1502375978/bedtime_stories_bywggz.jpg",
    musicSrc:
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/alick/video/upload/v1502375674/Bedtime_Stories.mp3"
  }
];

const audioList3 = [
  {
    name: "Despacito",
    singer: "Luis Fonsi",
    cover:
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/alick/image/upload/v1502689731/Despacito_uvolhp.jpg",
    musicSrc:
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/alick/video/upload/v1502689683/Luis_Fonsi_-_Despacito_ft._Daddy_Yankee_uyvqw9.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Bedtime Stories",
    singer: "Jay Chou",
    cover:
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/alick/image/upload/v1502375978/bedtime_stories_bywggz.jpg",
    musicSrc:
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/alick/video/upload/v1502375674/Bedtime_Stories.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Dorost Nemisham",
    singer: "Sirvan Khosravi",
    cover:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/ehsanahmadi/image/upload/v1573758778/Sirvan-Khosravi-Dorost-Nemisham_glicks.jpg",
    musicSrc:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/ehsanahmadi/video/upload/v1573550770/Sirvan-Khosravi-Dorost-Nemisham-128_kb8urq.mp3"
  }
];

const options = {
  audioLists: audioList1,
  clearPriorAudioLists: true
};

const SideMenu = () => {
  const { options, setOptions } = useContext(AppContext);

  // nit check if Sidemenu is inside AppContext - omitted here
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
      <h2>SideMenu</h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => setOptions({ ...options, audioLists: audioList1 })}>
        Playlist1
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => setOptions({ ...options, audioLists: audioList2 })}>
        Playlist2
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => setOptions({ ...options, audioLists: audioList3 })}>
        Playlist3
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const AppContext = createContext({
  options,
  setOptions: () => {}
});

function App(props) {
  const [playerOptions, setPlayerOptions] = useState(options);
  const [sideBarFull] = useState(true);

  const userSettings = {
    playerOptions,
    setPlayerOptions
  };

  /*const PageHeader = () => {
    return (
      <div className="h-[72px] w-full flex items-center align-middle justify-center 
 bg-neutral shadow">
    <div className="w-full text-center">
      <Header />
    </div>
  </div>
);
  };*/

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{ options: playerOptions, setOptions: setPlayerOptions }}
    >
      <div className="relative w-full min-h-screen min-w-[480px] h-full">
        <div className="flex flex-row min-h-screen">
          <div className="w-auto z-0 ">
            <div className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen mx-auto text-lg h-full shadow-lg bg-white overflow-y-auto">
              <SideMenu showFullMenu={sideBarFull} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="w-full max-h-screen flex flex-col z-10">
            {/*<PageHeader />*/}
            <div className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen mx-auto text-lg h-full shadow-lg bg-white overflow-y-auto">
              {/*<AppRoutes />*/}
              <ReactJkMusicPlayer {...playerOptions} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-jinke-music-player@4.24.2/lib/index.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-jinke-music-player@4.24.2/assets/index.css">

<div id="root"></div>
```